# Remote Desktop to EC2 Instance on Port 80 or 443

Tags: amazon-ec2, remote-desktop

I created a small EC2 instance running Windows Server, and opened up ports 80, 443, and 3389. 
I needed to Remote Desktop into it from work where the outbound firewall only allows 80 and 443. So I modified the registry entry as outlined in [this document](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306759) to have Terminal Server listen on port 443.

However when I tested it by pointing Remote Desktop to the address and port ( ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:443 ) it wouldn't connect. I was testing this from home, not from work, where a standard connection was working fine before I changed it.

Why not? Could it be that Amazon doesn't allow RDP traffic over ports 80 and 443?

Or, is it possible that Windows Firewall on my desktop is interfering somehow?

Comment: As an aside, now it is impossible to Remote into the instance at all. This was just a test though, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your security groups in your AWS panel. Make sure you allow incoming connection on the ports you are using.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer...I double-checked and ports 80/443/3389 are all open.